# Does GNU radio Stick has an inbuilt High pass filter in hardware level or is it implemented while designing the blocks?

Tags: gnu, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

Im trying to transmit analog message signals which are of 10hz frequency through fm modulation. The tests message signal was a simple sine wave. I am using rtl_sdr and gnu radio companion to receive this transmitted signals and demodulate it. i am only able to properly reproduce signals above 1KHz. below that frequency the amplitude of the signals are also decreasing as i keep reducing down the message signal frequency. i want to know if there is a high pass filter present or not? if it is present, where? is it in the hardware  level or is it present in the software blocks which i use? and how do i change it?

the flow of the fm receiver is as in the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxhMB.jpg)

Comment: GNU Radio is a software project – your question hence makes no sense; GNU Radio is just software running on your PC.

Comment: also, your OS has a screenshot functionality, and your GRC has a "save screenshot" button. Please don't post slanted, unevenly lit camera pictures of flow graphs.

Comment: so is there any high pass filter in the wbfm receive block already coded into it?